# Goodness-of-fit test for very skewed data

Tags: probability, distributions, chi-squared-test, goodness-of-fit, frequency

I am working with two quite large datasets (9000 obs and 3800 obs). Each observation has been grouped into 1 of 12 categories and I am looking to test if the frequency of categories in the smaller dataset follows the same distribution as in the larger dataset.

I can visually see that it does, but I'm having issues statistically testing it.

The problem is that the frequency of each category differs quite a lot, with some categories having ~1000 observations, and others close to 0 observations. I've determined that a chi-squared goodness-of-fit test is not optimal, due to some low observed frequencies, and when I've tried do conduct G-tests I get G values of around 1000-3000, with p < 2e-16. I'm guessing because of the large differences in my dataset, I get an elevated G-value and very significant results.

I am now looking into maybe testing each category individually, comparing the observed value with the expected value (calculated from the proportions of categories from my larger dataset), and calculating confidence intervals. Would this be an appropriate method?

I'm adding a graph of my two distributions to better visualize the problem, with "sailor" representing the larger dataset, and the "birds" representing the smaller.[image]

---

Following up on your answers, which I am very grateful for:

I see what you both mean, I was just uncertain about the appropriateness of conducting a chi-squared or G-test.

I here provide you with the expected vs. observed frequencies per category in a table.

I also performed binomial tests on each category, confirming what we then already seem to know. That there are significant differences in the frequencies of the different categories between the two datasets. With Category A:3, A:4 and C:4 having higher observed frequencies, and all other categories lower.

[image]

Comment: "I can visually see that it does", I don't see how

Comment: Okay maybe I should rephrase, I can visually see that it might differ. Of course I cannot be certain before testing it.

Comment: *Each observation has been grouped into 1 of 12 categories and I am looking to test if the frequency of categories in the smaller dataset follows the same distribution as in the larger dataset.*---I'm confused why the second plot doesn't have the same number of categories as the other if this is the statement you made. Surely if the categories aren't the same then it would be difficult to make very direct comparisons between the two.

Comment: A reasonable analytical strategy cannot be specified until you fully describe the ultimate aims of the analysis in non-statistical terms, and describe how the groups were determined.

Comment: What you've posted is not the raw frequencies of 9000 (or so) observations in one group and 3800 (or so) in another group. Almost always in problems like these expected frequencies have fractional parts.

Answer (score 8):

I wouldn't call these distributions "very skewed" on two grounds. The idea of skewness does not easily apply to categorical variables. Even if there is some kind of natural or conventional order to your variable, the frequency distributions are clearly uneven but not extraordinarily so.

Beyond that, chi-square testing shows overwhelming differences, so further inferential analysis is not really needed. You could look at individual so-called Pearson residuals, (observed $-$ expected) / root of expected, to see which categories deviate most from the null expectation.

It is low expected frequencies that are problematic for chi-square testing, not low observed frequencies.

To say more, we might need to see the frequencies tabled as well as plotted.

Comment: I posted a new answer and provided you with the frequency table.

Answer (score 7):

Your post reminds me of the guy who wouldn't accept "yes" for an answer.

G tests are quite similar to chi-square, but have some better properties. In your case, both give overwhelming evidence of a statistically significant difference.

Of course, a low p value isn't a guarantee of a substantively important difference, but in your case, it's pretty clear that the difference is important by any reasonable definition. I would show this graphically, not with separate bar charts but with a mosaic plot.

But your data also passes the IOTT: The interocular trauma test. It hits you between the eyes. If you found a test that said there was no difference in the distributions, then that would be a bad test.